# Copy value to another input with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input number fields that show total with some jQuery.

Calculate total:

```
$('form#lines-form-1 :input[type="number"]').change(function() {
  var tot = 0;
  $('form#lines-form-1 :input[type="number"]').each(function() {
    tot += +this.value;
  });
  $('#tot-qty').text(tot);
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q3z4w98o/2/

After entering some numbers on form A press Total to show results.

When clicked Copy how to transfer the total value to Form B's first input field?

E.g.

1. input1 has value 1
2. input2 has value 1
3. total = 2
4. click Copy
5. input3 gets a value of 2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ke09cpd/):

```
$("button.copy-btn").click(function() {
    $('input[name="i3"]').val($("#tot-qty").text());
})
```

This bit copies the text value inside the `#tot-qty` span and sets the `i3` input value to that when clicking the "Copy" button.